# Moving two divs to the center where one is a clone of another

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to move two divs to the center of the page. The right div is a clone of left div (The images of left div are cloned into right div). When I am trying to move the left div using the 'left:100px' the right is getting distorted. How can I move the two divs to the center. Kindly look at some of the lines of my cod below.

```js
var theRightSide= document.getElementById('rightside');
var leftimages= theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
leftimages.removeChild(leftimages.lastChild);
theRightSide.appendChild(leftimages);
```

```css
div {width: 600px; height: 600px}
#leftside {position: absolute;border: 3px solid black; background-color: lightYellow}
#rightside {position: absolute;left:600px;background-color: lightYellow}
```

```html
<div id="leftside"></div>
<div id="rightside"></div>
```

Comment: wrap them in a 3rd div with margin-left and margin-right set to auto

Comment: What do you want exactly?

Comment: What do you want exactly when simple css can make them inline

Comment: Using Css command 'left' when I try to move the left div even the right div is moving. So I unable to change the position to center. I think the reason is due  to the cloning. How can I change the position of left div without altering the position of the right div?

Comment: where did you define 'theLeftSide' on script line 2 ??

Comment: I have defined theLeftSide as:    var theLeftSide= document.getElementById("leftside");  and then appended some images into it. I have defined 'theLeftChild' before defining 'theRightside'.

Comment: And Please tell us the full details. why you need to to clone ?  when css can make both div into center

Comment: I am making a game which will have two divisions. One division( left) will have an extra image than the right division. The player has to find out the odd image.So to do that I have appended images into left and then cloned them into right and then deleted one image from right(last child). So now there are one less images in right than in left. After I had done everything, I would like to move the divisions to the center of the page. But I am unable to do. Is it clear ? @MostafaBaezid

Comment: delete left image after clone and show right image with left: 100px or more.. thats it

Comment: Thank you Mostafa Baezid. The answer from user2940296 has worked.

Comment: your welcome. that's why I told before css can do that without clone .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for this. because your making a game maybe you need this clone in future or some other project

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#leftside").clone().appendTo("#rightside");
 $("#rightside").css({
  "margin-left": "80px"
  });
   $("#leftside").fadeOut("slow").remove(fadeOut);
 });

  div {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px
  }
  #leftside {
   position: absolute;
   border: 3px solid black;
   background-color: lightYellow;
  }

 <div id="leftside">
 </div>
 <div id="rightside"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/u5xxky1s/2/

wish you all the best for your game. Happy coding

Comment: Thank you so much!.@MostafaBaezid

Answer (score 1):

Try using `display: inline-block;`

A very simple example to explain how it works-

```css
.outer-box {
position: absolute;
left: 17%;
}
.box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 3px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-box">
<div class="box">Box 1</div>
<div class="box">Box 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!. This is the exact answer that I am waiting for. Now I am able to move the divisions to the center. Once again thank you @user2940296.